# Decorating a sitemap view in Django

Tags: python, django, decorator, sitemap

I have a few hundred thousand URLs, so I'd like to cache my sitemaps. This generates the sitemap just fine:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap, views as sitemap_views

class StuffSitemap(Sitemap):
    limit = 1000

    def items(self):
        return Stuff.objects.all().order_by('date')

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap_views.index, {'sitemaps': {'stuff': StuffSitemap()}}),
    url(r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$', sitemap_views.sitemap, {'sitemaps': {'stuff': StuffSitemap()}}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    ...
]
```

Decorating the `sitemap.xml` index view works fine (even with my own decorators):

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', cache_control(max_age=3600, public=True)(sitemap_views.index), {'sitemaps': {'stuff': StuffSitemap()}}),
```

But the moment I decorate the actual sitemap view, things start breaking:

```
url(r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$', cache_control(max_age=3600, public=True)(sitemap_views.sitemap), {'sitemaps': {'stuff': StuffSitemap()}}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap')
```

Here's the full traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /sitemap.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/blender/Projects/project/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 104, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/blender/Projects/project/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/middleware.py", line 77, in process_view
    response = panel.process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs)
  File "/Users/blender/Projects/project/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar_line_profiler/panel.py", line 176, in process_view
    out = self.profiler.runcall(view_func, *args, **view_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cProfile.py", line 149, in runcall
    return func(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/blender/Projects/project/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/views.py", line 17, in inner
    response = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/blender/Projects/project/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/views.py", line 37, in index
    sitemap_url_name, kwargs={'section': section})
  File "/Users/blender/Projects/project/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 551, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/blender/Projects/project/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 468, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'section': 'stuff'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Curiously, both of these views are decorated when they're defined:

```
def x_robots_tag(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response['X-Robots-Tag'] = 'noindex, noodp, noarchive'
        return response
    return inner


@x_robots_tag
def index(request, sitemaps,
          template_name='sitemap_index.xml', content_type='application/xml',
          sitemap_url_name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'):
    ....
```

It seems to me that the decorator is preventing the Django url mapper from treating the decorated `sitemap` view properly, as it uses `**kwargs` instead of an explicit `section` kwarg:

```
sitemap_url = urlresolvers.reverse(sitemap_url_name, kwargs={'section': section})
```

But this doesn't explain why it works to begin with, as the views are already decorated. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of the url for you sectioned sitemap away from ```django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap```?

Comment: @schillingt: Yep. I added that when Django threw the error, but it makes no difference.

Comment: What django version are you using? I'm using 1.4 and I have the same problem

Comment: @ark: I'm using 1.7.8. I think it's present in 1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

I am caching my sitemap by creating a view function and returning the built-in django sitemap view:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap


@cache_page(60*60*1)
def sitemap_view(request):
    return sitemap(request, sitemaps)

urlpatterns = [
    path('sitemap.xml', sitemap_view, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap')
]
```